# How to visualize a .pfm file as image?

Tags: image, image-processing, computer-vision, data-visualization

I have a .pfm which is a (.PF/.pf) file. I am trying to visualize it but I am unable to do so. Normally the .pfm files contain the header of the format.

1. PF/pf
2. width height
3. scale=1

But my file has this header.I am unable to visualize it as the image can anyone help me out. Any help is appreciated

1. Typ=Pic98::TPlane
2. Lines=750
3. Columns=1125
4. FirstLine=0
5. FirstColumn=0

   ```
   import re
   import numpy as np
   file = open("PF file.PF", 'rb')
   header = file.readline().rstrip().decode('utf-8')
   if header == 'PF':
      raise Exception('Only ONE channel image is supported.')
   elif header == 'Typ=Pic98::TPlane<float>':
       color = False
   else:
       raise Exception('Not a PFM file.')
   dim_match = re.match(r'(^(\w+).(\d+)$)\n(^(\w+).(\d+)\s$)', 
   file.readline().decode('ascii'))
   if dim_match:
     width, height = map(int, dim_match.groups())
   else:
     raise Exception('Malformed PFM header.')
   if header == 'Typ=Pic98::TPlane<float>':
     scale =1
     endian = '>'
   else:
     scale = -scale
     endian = '<'

   npImage = np.reshape(npImage, width,height)
   npImage = np.flipud(npImage)

   if ret_PIL:
     img = Image.fromarray(npImage, 'F')
     return img
   return npImage
   file.close()
   ```

Comment: I made an application on windows for that https://github.com/SiliconStudio/PfmViewer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

I have re-written my answer below in a slightly different, hopefully clearer style.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import re
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

def readPF(filename):
   """Read named PF file into Numpy array"""

   # Slurp entire file into memory as binary 'bytes'
   with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
      data = f.read()

   # Check correct header, return None if incorrect
   if not re.match(b'Typ=Pic98::TPlane<float>', data):
      return None
   
   # Get Lines and Columns, both must be present, else return None
   L = re.search(b'Lines=(\d+)',   data)
   C = re.search(b'Columns=(\d+)', data)
   if not (L and C):
      return None
   height = int(L.groups()[0])
   width  = int(C.groups()[0])
   print(f'DEBUG: Height={height}, width={width}')

   # Take the data from the END of the file in case other header lines added at start
   na = np.frombuffer(data[-4*height*width:], dtype=np.dtype('<f4')).reshape((height,width))

   # Some debug stuff
   min, max, mean = na.min(), na.max(), na.mean()
   print(f'DEBUG: min={min}, max={max}, mean={mean}')

   return na

################################################################################
# Main
################################################################################
na = readPF('PF file.PF')

################################################################################
# Use either of the following to save the image:
################################################################################
# Save with OpenCV as scaled PNG
u16 = (65535*(na - np.min(na))/np.ptp(na)).astype(np.uint16)  
cv2.imwrite('OpenCV.png', u16)

# Convert to PIL Image and save as TIFF
pi = Image.fromarray(na, mode='F')
pi.save('PIL.tif')
```

**Original Answer**

Not too sure what I image I should be expecting, but here is a rough idea:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import re
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

file = open("PF file.PF", 'rb')
header = file.readline().rstrip().decode('utf-8')
if header == 'PF':
   raise Exception('Only ONE channel image is supported.')
elif header == 'Typ=Pic98::TPlane<float>':
    color = False
else:
    raise Exception('Not a PFM file.')

while True:
    line = file.readline().decode('ascii')
    match = re.match('(\w+)=(\d+)', line)
    n, v = match.groups()
    if n == 'Lines':
        height = int(v)
        print(f'Height: {height}')
    if n == 'Columns':
        width = int(v)
        print(f'Width: {width}')
        break

# Seek backwards from the end of the file in case any clown has added something to the header
file.seek(-height*width*4,2)

# Read remainder of file into Numpy array of floats and reshape
na = np.fromfile(file, dtype=np.float32).reshape((height,width))

# Some debug stuff
min, max, mean = na.min(), na.max(), na.mean()
print(f'DEBUG: min={min}, max={max}, mean={mean}')

################################################################################
# Use either of the following to save the image:
################################################################################
# Save with OpenCV as scaled PNG
u16 = (65535*(na - np.min(na))/np.ptp(na)).astype(np.uint16)  
cv2.imwrite('OpenCV.png', u16)

# Convert to PIL Image and save as TIFF
pi = Image.fromarray(na, mode='F')
pi.save('PIL.tif')
```

[image]

The output is as follows:

```
Height: 750
Width: 1125
DEBUG: min=0.0, max=127881704.0, mean=1618343.625
```

---

Another possibility is to use **ImageMagick** to make it into a PNG, I get the following, and **ImageMagick** defaults to little-endian, so if this is correct, your image is little endian.

```
magick -define quantum:format=floating-point -depth 32 -size 1125x750+80 gray:"PF file.pf"  -auto-level image.png
```

[image]

**Keywords**: Python, ImageMagick, image processing, float, float32, Numpy, PFM

Comment: Thank you so much for the help and yes this is the expected image. I have a small question when saving the image you used scaling how did you know the scaled value? Can you tell me I just want to know I am curious about it

Comment: You are welcome. The code can be improved, but I'll leave that up to you - it should be easy enough now that you have something that works to get started with. Good luck with your project.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help and wishes. Good luck to you too

Comment: As regards the scaling, I just made it full-scale, so that the darkest pixel in your image comes out as black and the brightest comes out white, everything else linearly in-between. I got the range of values in your image with the `np.ptp()` which gives me the peak-to-peak range. I then scaled that over 16-bits (which is better than the 8-bits you'd get in a JPEG) and saved as PNG because that supports 16-bit and is readable by anything. The TIFF I saved is a more *"true"* representation if you want to process further, but less accessible for simple viewing.

Comment: Hi when running the code on my computer it shows me a full black image

Comment: Did all three methods show a black image - I mean the PNG and the TIFF and the **ImageMagick** JPEG? Did you use the exact same input file?

Comment: Hi yes I used te exact same input file PNG was black and the TIFF was black and the part in the middle was white

Comment: Here are the links for the same image saved, 1(https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_k2kIatdIxzqkskgle45NozuML9VPKZu/view?usp=sharing) ,    2(https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lDNtmQvarsi8QhhRmkgU1QV8zXLfV2aJ/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can you share the output files you got please? Dropbox or Google Drive or similar.

Comment: Here I have added them again 
1(https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_k2kIatdIxzqkskgle45NozuML9VPKZu/view?usp=sharing) ,    2(https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lDNtmQvarsi8QhhRmkgU1QV8zXLfV2aJ/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Weird! Try changing `dtype=np.float32` to `dtype=np.dtype('<f4')`

Comment: I changed it but it is still the same

Comment: Mmmm, getting lost for ideas now. Can you try copying my code again and pasting and running that - there is a bit more debug stuff in there.

Comment: Hi I tried again with the debug it didn't change anything but I got these as output                                                          Height: 750
Width: 1125
DEBUG: min=1.1693418049840562e-19, max=1.9205795879290584e+31, mean=2.276379638994864e+25

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1S2wK-MZjgo4HIuZMBlSPXqaUGl7PfIz-/view?usp=sharing    This is the code I used for the execution.

Comment: Ok, so it's not your OpenCV or PIL that's different, so it can only be your endianness, or the seeking. So, can you try the `dtype=np.dtype('<f4')` one more time with the latest code please?

Comment: I changed it  and tried again its the same black screen and the tiff image is same as the link I shared before

Comment: Ok, and one more idea. Copy the line starting `file.seek(...)` and paste it immediately below itself and then insert the following line between the two copies `print(len(file.read()))` to see if we are both the same distance from the end of file.

Comment: I tried reshaping with different method but the results are same      https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dLCmldUhl2zWBGZrN_n6ISw7DBLmmcyk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please try to work from my code above, it has `65535` not `65525` and it has `np.uint16` not `np.uint32`. Also, your code should have printed the length of the `file.read()` between the **two** `seek()` statements - what was that value please?

Comment: I got an error  at na = np.fromfile line                                                                   ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 0 into shape (750,1125)

Comment: Hi it was a mistake so sorry for that, I accidentally copied it on the other one. Now I did copy the new one I am adding the screenshot.                                                https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GOc5ho8wS9smZFG4uPraHbddZRF35msi/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I see. The `print()` needs to be **between** the two `file.seek()` statements.

Comment: I got this output                                                          Height: 750
Width: 1125
3375000
DEBUG: min=1.1693418049840562e-19, max=1.9205795879290584e+31, mean=2.276379638994864e+25
True

Comment: I'll think some more about this - I have no idea for the moment. I have to go out, but maybe you could check the MD5 checksum of your image file. I get 4d31a01177f2530280a2c37de3dbf7ef on my machine.

Comment: I got this for PNG bf0b64fef4f19689de92a28f593f4fef                                                    
 and for tiff(49775fb439bda8ff06b229f7eb50a2f0)

Comment: I was checking the MD5 of the source file, i.e. the `.pf` file, to make sure we are working off the same input,

Comment: Hi MD5 checksum for the updated google drive file is 4d31a01177f2530280a2c37de3dbf7ef and the file I have on my computer has checksum of 9b52b37637578dfb875815f26f122c3f. They both are the same files I just uploaded one in google drive for sharing here.

Comment: Hello, For the file I downloaded from google drive works I got the output but I have issues with the source file. I don't know what's wrong with it.                                          Thank you so much for sticking through and helping me out it was so nice to talk to you. HAPPY EASTER !!!

Comment: Pleasure! You too.

Comment: The contrast range is too enormous. If you use a histogram equalisation method you can see the image really clearly. Can you use **ImageMagick**? If so, this command works well `magick -define quantum:format=floating-point -depth 32 -size 1920x937+80 gray:"sidelight.pf"  -equalize  image.png`

Comment: If you are using OpenCV, you can add CLAHE in as the last step before saving the image https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.0/d5/daf/tutorial_py_histogram_equalization.html

Comment: Thank you so much mark. Man, I wanna learn things from you and gain knowledge.  Have a nice evening. Have a good day and stay safe.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this cvkit tool https://github.com/roboception/cvkit on Mac and Ubuntu. It works very well to visualize '.pfm' files (e.g., disparity or depth maps saved as pfm file).